# Variable labels on multiple lines in LaTeX when exporting results with esttab

Tags: latex, stata

I am trying to export some regression results to `LaTeX` using the *community-contributed* command `estate` in Stata. I want to use variable *labels* instead of variable names, but some of the labels are so long that the width of the table does not fit nicely on the page once I export it to `LaTeX`.

Example data can be found below:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input double areakey float(state d1 d2) int(bfunemp otnenon bmunemp)
1015001100 1 0 1   0 26  0
1033020701 1 0 1  27  1 33
1073003803 1 0 1 208  0 78
1073005702 1 0 1  76  0 88
1073011904 1 0 1  35  0 44
1073013200 1 0 1  11  0 59
1097006407 1 0 0   0  0  9
1097007300 1 0 1   9  0  0
1111000600 1 0 0   6  0  1
1115040201 1 0 0   4  0  2
1115040204 1 0 0   3  5  6
1117030317 1 1 1   0  0  0
1117030320 1 0 0  11  0  0
1117030336 1 0 0   0  0  0
1125011600 1 0 1  91  0 88
1125011701 1 0 1  73  0 41
4013112100 4 0 0   0  0  0
4013112301 4 0 1   8  0 25
4013112601 4 0 1   0  0  0
4013112700 4 0 0   0  0  0
end
label var areakey "GEOID10" 
label var state "State FIPS code" 
label var d1 "Distance <= 1 Dummy" 
label var d2 "Distance <= 2 Dummy" 
label var bfunemp "Unemployed Black/Afr. Am. females 16+ yo." 
label var otnenon "Pers. 18-64 yo. other lang. not well/no Eng." 
label var bmunemp "Unemployed Black/Afr. Am. males 16+ yo."
```

In addition, the code I am using is the following:

```
global xvars bfunemp otnenon bmunemp

eststo mreg1: quietly areg d1 $xvars, absorb(state) robust /// 
   cluster(state)
eststo mreg2: quietly areg d2 $xvars, absorb(state) robust /// 
   cluster(state)

keep if indicatorvar > 0

eststo mreg3: quietly areg d1 $xvars, absorb(state) robust /// 
   cluster(state)
eststo mreg4: quietly areg d2 $xvars, absorb(state) robust /// 
   cluster(state)

esttab mreg1 mreg3 mreg2 mreg4 using /// 
   "$repodir/output/tables/tract_mregs.tex", ///
   replace booktabs longtable mtitles("y1" "y1" "y2" "y2") /// 
   s(modelsample modelobs, label("Sample" "N")) se /// 
   noconstant nonumbers nonotes label star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01)
```

The result after I compile the `TeX` file is a table where the left margin is fine but the contents of the table extend off the right side of the page such that there is no margin.

Is there a way of specifying the format so that the labels can extend to multiple lines?

Comment: `indicatorvar` does not exist in the example dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting option `longtable` with `wrap` will produce the desired output after you compile:

```
esttab mreg1 mreg3 mreg2 mreg4, tex wrap ///
   mtitles("y1" "y1" "y2" "y2") /// 
   s(modelsample modelobs, label("Sample" "N")) se /// 
   noconstant nonumbers nonotes label star(* 0.10 ** 0.05 *** 0.01)

{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{y1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{y1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{y2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{y2}
> \\
\hline
Unemployed          &  -0.0000359         &  -0.0000359         &   -0.000489         &   -0.000489         \\
Black/Afr. Am. females 16+ yo.& (0.0000876)         & (0.0000876)         &  (0.000770)         &  (0.000770)   
>       \\
[1em]
Pers. 18-64 yo.     &    -0.00555\sym{**} &    -0.00555\sym{**} &      0.0244\sym{**} &      0.0244\sym{**} \\
other lang. not well/no Eng.&  (0.000143)         &  (0.000143)         &   (0.00126)         &   (0.00126)     
>     \\
[1em]
Unemployed          &    -0.00180\sym{*}  &    -0.00180\sym{*}  &      0.0109         &      0.0109         \\
Black/Afr. Am. males 16+ yo.&  (0.000221)         &  (0.000221)         &   (0.00194)         &   (0.00194)     
>     \\
\hline
Sample              &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
N                   &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
}
```

In addition, the option `varwidth()` can also help adjusting the length of the first column.